# Не получается минимизировать функцию потерь

Tags: python, функции, numpy, scipy

Пытаюсь минимизировать функцию потерь радикальных оценок для оценки параметров нормального распределения

[image: 1]

Мой код выглядит следующим образом:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
from scipy.optimize import minimize
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
def oro(theta, x):
    norma = 0 
    b = 1
    mean = theta[0]
    std = theta[1]
    x = np.array(x)
    x0 = 0
    f0 = -(((1/(std*(2*np.pi)**(0.5)))*(np.exp(1))**-(((x0-mean)**2)/(2*(std**2))))**b)**-1
    for i in range(x.size):
        f = (1/(std*(2*np.pi)**(0.5)))*(np.exp(1))**-(((x[i]-mean)**2)/(2*(std**2)))**b
        norma += f0*f
    return norma
theta_init = [0, 1]
res = minimize(oro, theta_init, args=x)
res
```

Но на выходе появляется ошибка:

```
<ipython-input-244-b51d0c455468>:8: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  f0 = -(((1/(std*(2*np.pi)**(0.5)))*(np.exp(1))**-(((x0-mean)**2)/(2*(std**2))))**b)**-1
<ipython-input-244-b51d0c455468>:11: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  norma += f0*f
<ipython-input-244-b51d0c455468>:8: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  f0 = -(((1/(std*(2*np.pi)**(0.5)))*(np.exp(1))**-(((x0-mean)**2)/(2*(std**2))))**b)**-1
<ipython-input-244-b51d0c455468>:11: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  norma += f0*f
<ipython-input-244-b51d0c455468>:8: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  f0 = -(((1/(std*(2*np.pi)**(0.5)))*(np.exp(1))**-(((x0-mean)**2)/(2*(std**2))))**b)**-1
<ipython-input-244-b51d0c455468>:11: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  norma += f0*f
      fun: nan
 hess_inv: array([[9.60440620e+02, 2.42216097e+01],
       [2.42216097e+01, 8.34817024e-01]])
      jac: array([nan, nan])
  message: 'Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.'
     nfev: 357
      nit: 4
     njev: 119
   status: 2
  success: False
        x: array([166092.13702358,   1772.7446745 ])
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Добавил ограничения по совету:

```
res = minimize(oro, theta_init, args=x, bounds=((None, None), (1e-4, None)))
```

Но все равно получается ошибка на выходе:

```
<ipython-input-271-b51d0c455468>:8: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  f0 = -(((1/(std*(2*np.pi)**(0.5)))*(np.exp(1))**-(((x0-mean)**2)/(2*(std**2))))**b)**-1
<ipython-input-271-b51d0c455468>:11: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  norma += f0*f
      fun: nan
 hess_inv: <2x2 LbfgsInvHessProduct with dtype=float64>
      jac: array([-0.00012861,  0.00018581])
  message: 'ABNORMAL_TERMINATION_IN_LNSRCH'
     nfev: 75
      nit: 2
     njev: 25
   status: 2
  success: False
        x: array([250.13040562, 343.06899721])
```

Comment: Импорты добавьте

Comment: Что за магическая функция minimize?

Comment: Добавил импорты

Comment: У вас там похоже переполнение происходит. Если сделаете печать `print(u,o)` внутри функции, они там улетают за `1e+60`, а потом видимо переполняются и обратно сбрасываются. Не знаю, почему минимум не ищется.